# Alternating input from different .txt files

Tags: input

I'm trying to create a pdf which contains news articles, showing their url, the title, and the first paragraph or the article. These 3 are stored on 3 different .txt files and each have a line for themselves. If I use `\input{}` for the 3 files, I would get all the links, then all the titles, then all the paragraphs. Is there a way to input the contents of the files so that it goes `file 1 line 1, file 2 line 1, file 3 line 1, file 1 line 2, file 2 line 2...`.

Comment: Welcome. // Please try to add some reduced code to your question, which we can copy and compile. Your input statements and the file contents would be interesting. // BTW, this is a perfect task for databases. Did you consider that alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\read` primitive, no `\input` primitive. The `\read` primitive has following syntax:

```
\read \filedesc to\macro
```

and it reads next single line and saves it to the `\macro`.
The `\filedesc` must be declared by `\newread` macro and initialized by `\openin` primitive. The full code which reads lines from `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` looks like this:

```
\newread\fA \newread\fB \newread\fC

\openin\fA=file1.txt \openin\fB=file2.txt \openin\fC=file3.txt

\read\fA to\tmp  \tmp % prints file 1, line 1
\read\fB to\tmp  \tmp % prints file 2, line 1
\read\fC to\tmp  \tmp % prints file 3, line 1

\read\fA to\tmp  \tmp % prints file 1, line 2
\read\fB to\tmp  \tmp % prints file 2, line 2
\read\fC to\tmp  \tmp % prints file 3, line 2

\read\fA to\tmp  \tmp % prints file 1, line 3
\read\fB to\tmp  \tmp % prints file 2, line 3
\read\fC to\tmp  \tmp % prints file 3, line 3

\bye
```